# C# - Remove items from List when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My problem is; When click a button I input items in List, **next** in DropDownList. Problem is where i click button again exist items again into my DropDown.

How to solve this problem(*sorry for image)*?

[image]

```
   List<string> companyList = new List<string>();

   foreach (string item in companyList.ToList())
   {
     companyList.Remove(item); ----> this not working.......
   }

   foreach (SPListItem item in myItemCol)
   {
     companyList.Add(item["Company"].ToString());
   }

   companyList.Sort();

   foreach (string item in companyList.Distinct())
   {
      ddComFilter.Items.Add(item.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: You could just check if an item is already in the list, and then don't add it

Comment: Why not working? Any errors?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you want? Please post all methods here including your page load method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear your dropdown before adding list as items:

```
   companyList.Sort();

   ddComFilter.Items.Clear();  // clear
   foreach (string item in companyList.Distinct())
   {
      ddComFilter.Items.Add(item.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: You should be more clear, and explain little more while answering. you have lots of unwanted codes in the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Contains` method to check if it is already there

```
if(!ddComFilter.Items.Contains(items.ToString())
{
    ddComFilter.Items.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

This will only add the item if it is not already in the dropdown

Answer (score 3):

You could check for existence of the item before add it to the list.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in myItemCol)
   {
     if(!companyList.Contains(item["Company"].ToString())
     {
       companyList.Add(item["Company"].ToString());
     }
   }
```

Then you need to clear the `ddComFilter` before adding the values to it:

```
companyList.Sort();
ddComFilter.Items.Clear();
foreach (string item in companyList.Distinct())
   {
      ddComFilter.Items.Add(item.ToString());
   }
```

**Alternate solution**:

You can bind the `ddComFilter` using the generated list, instead for iterating the collection and add one-by-one. if so you need not to clear the collection, remove items etc. The code for this will be:

```
ddComFilter.Datasource = companyList;
ddComFilter.DataBind();
```

Here is an useful [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/303564/Binding-DropDownList-Using-List-Collection-Enum-an) for you

Comment: I think this is the wrong part of the code, this is where he populates the list which inputs into the dropdown, which may not have any values in it to begin with even if the dropdown does

Comment: I had some updates; please check that, Clear the list before adding; `ddComFilter.Items.Clear();`